# Using lag() to compare rows within the same dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe, locations_gps that contains numerous gps records. The structure of the dataframe is as such:

```
structure(list(Timestamp = structure(c(1388960881, 1388960881, 1388960883, 1388960885, 1388960886, 1388960887), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), id = c(35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35), lat = c(36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762, 36.0762), long = c(24.8747, 24.8746, 24.8744, 24.8743, 24.8742, 24.8741)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The intention is to create a new column(min3) that has a 3 min delay. For instance, if the timestamp is 12pm, the value for min3 would be 12:03pm. And then I will check the lat/long at 12:03pm and verify if the lat/long at 12:03pm corresponds with the one 12:00pm.

However, since the records are recorded at either 1 or 2 seconds interval, if there is no record at 12:03:00, then it can search for 12:03:01 or 02 or so on (probably up to 30s), to see if there is any record.

The idea for doing this is to identify Point-of-Interests among a set of GPS data.

My problem is whether my understanding of lag() is correct. It seems like no matter there I were to change the min3 to a 3 mins lag, or 5 mins lag, or even 1 hour lag, the result would be the same. The code is as such:

```
POI_gps <- locations_gps %>%
  mutate(min3 = Timestamp + 60*3) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(stay = if_else(min3 <= lag(min3) & lat == lag(lat) & long == lag(long), TRUE, FALSE)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(stay == TRUE) %>%
  distinct(lat, long)
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Why not just calculate the offset of each row from the target datetime and then select the row with the smallest offset?  [There are obvious opportunities for efficiency, but that's the skeleton of a solution.]  Also, look at the `lubridate` package for more transparent handling of datetimes, periods, durations and differences between them. [I shudder at `60*3`....]

Comment: how would the code be like if I would like to check POI_gps$Timestamp with the POI_gps$Timestamp that is 3 mins away and then look at the lat/long? If the lat/long were to be correct, I will flag it as TRUE. And if there is no data at exactly 3 mins away, how do I make them check down another 30 seconds, and then if there are no data, then return as FALSE?

Comment: Please provide a more meaningful inpout dataset (all (`lat`, `long`) pairs 9and values of `id`) are identical in your sample) together with the corresponding expected output.  What defines a "point of interest": being stationary for <x> minutes?

Comment: Is it true that lag() will only look at the next row (observation) while lead() will look at the previous row (observation)?

Comment: It's the other way round: `lag()` looks backwards, towards the first row, `lead()` looks forwards, towards the last row.  You can control how many rows away each function looks.  It's all in the online doc.  Their behaviour is slightly modified if the tibble is grouped.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications! so if I would need to look forward 100 rows, it would be lead(x, k = 100) while if I look backwards a 100 rows, it would be lag(x, k = 100)?